# Professional menu with JavaScript and jQuery (part two)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

With the help of `Michael M.` I edited my WordPress menu code in the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75504472/professional-menu-with-javascript-and-jquery) nicely.

Now I want to open the submenu slowly whenever every `li` is clicked if there is a `ul` under it, which I wrote this code but in addition to opening the sub menu, I want the `right` direction sign `(→)` to the `down` direction sign `(↓ )` to change.

I have put all the code of this professional menu below, but my problem is only related to the last script code.

```js
let icon = document.querySelector(".icon_menu");
let nav = document.querySelector(".main_menu");

$('.back').hide();
$('.back').click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':hidden')) return;
  $(this).toggle();

  icon.classList = "bi bi-grid-fill icon_menu";
  icon.style.left = "2%";
  icon.style.color = "#a66fff";
  icon.style.fontSize = "40px";

  nav.style.left = '-300px';
});

icon.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (this.classList.contains("bi-grid-fill")) {
    this.classList = "bi bi-x-circle-fill icon_menu";
    icon.style.left = "21%";
    icon.style.color = "#ff6f6f";
    icon.style.fontSize = "30px";

    nav.style.left = 0;
  } else {
    this.classList = "bi bi-grid-fill icon_menu";
    icon.style.left = "2%";
    icon.style.color = "#a66fff";
    icon.style.fontSize = "40px";

    nav.style.left = "-300px";
  }
  $('.back').toggle();
});

//********************** **A script that needs editing** *********************

$('.main_menu').find('li').click(function(sub_menu) {
  sub_menu.stopPropagation();
  sub_menu.preventDefault();
  $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();

  if ($(this).is(style.content = ' → ')) {
    this.style.content = " ↓ ";
  };
});
```

```css
.main_menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -300px;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  background: #eee;
  padding-right: 2rem;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.icon_menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10%;
  left: 2%;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #a66fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 99999;
  transition: all 1.1s ease;
}

.main_menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 35px;
}

.main_menu ul li a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  margin-left: -60px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.back {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9 !important;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #00000056;
}

.main_menu ul li ul {
  display: none;
}

.main_menu ul li>a::after {
  content: ' → ';
}

.main_menu ul li:first-child>a::after {
  content: ' → ';
}

.main_menu ul li>a:only-child::after {
  content: '  ';
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <nav id="nav">
    <span class="bi bi-grid-fill icon_menu"></span>
    <aside class="main_menu">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">home</a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="#">our articles</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">social</a>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a href="#">Academic</a>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a href="#">historical</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">about us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </aside>
  </nav>
</section>
<div class="back"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably best to do this with CSS instead of JavaScript. Just add the `submenu` class to any `<li>` elements that hold sub-menus. Then, create an `open` class that will be toggled from the JavaScript. From your `click` handler, all you need to do is toggle the `open` class.

Because you're using WordPress and can't give elements classes directly, you can use some JavaScript trickery to assign the `submenu` class to each `li` in the `main_menu` that has a `ul` child.

Like this:

```js
let icon = document.querySelector(".icon_menu");
let nav = document.querySelector(".main_menu");

$('.back').hide();
$('.back').click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':hidden')) return;
  $(this).toggle();

  icon.classList = "bi bi-grid-fill icon_menu";
  icon.style.left = "2%";
  icon.style.color = "#a66fff";
  icon.style.fontSize = "40px";

  nav.style.left = '-300px';
});

icon.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (this.classList.contains("bi-grid-fill")) {
    this.classList = "bi bi-x-circle-fill icon_menu";
    icon.style.left = "21%";
    icon.style.color = "#ff6f6f";
    icon.style.fontSize = "30px";

    nav.style.left = 0;
  } else {
    this.classList = "bi bi-grid-fill icon_menu";
    icon.style.left = "2%";
    icon.style.color = "#a66fff";
    icon.style.fontSize = "40px";

    nav.style.left = "-300px";
  }
  $('.back').toggle();
});

//********************** **A script that needs editing** *********************

// hack to give the 'submenu' class
$('.main_menu li ul').each(function() {
  $(this).parent().addClass('submenu')
})

$('.submenu').click(function(sub_menu) {
  sub_menu.stopPropagation();
  sub_menu.preventDefault();
  $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
  $(this).toggleClass('open');
});
```

```css
.main_menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -300px;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  background: #eee;
  padding-right: 2rem;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.icon_menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10%;
  left: 2%;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #a66fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 99999;
  transition: all 1.1s ease;
}

.main_menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 35px;
}

.main_menu ul li a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  margin-left: -60px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.back {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9 !important;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #00000056;
}

.main_menu ul li ul {
  display: none;
}

.main_menu .submenu > a::after {
  content: ' → ';
}

.main_menu .open > a::after {
  content: ' ↓ ' !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <nav id="nav">
    <span class="bi bi-grid-fill icon_menu"></span>
    <aside class="main_menu">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">home</a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="#">our articles</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">social</a>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a href="#">Academic</a>
            </li>

            <li>
              <a href="#">historical</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">about us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </aside>
  </nav>
</section>
<div class="back"></div>
```

Comment: Since I am using WordPress, it is not possible for me to give a class to <li>. Is it possible to do this without giving a class to <li>?

Comment: @Developer I've edited my answer. You can use some JavaScript to assign the class to every element that is a submenu.

Comment: Your answer was more complete and better. But by adding the code (.main_menu li>a:only-child::after {
     content: '';
}) to the css file, I fixed this problem. Thank you again for your help.